# Format number to include text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, number-formatting

i feel like I've searched high and low for answers to this, what feels like an easy issue, with no luck.

I am trying to format a number in VBA to include a specific text, just like i can do in excel.

e.g. i have a number 3, which i want to format to show "Workday 3"

Excel: `"Workday" Standard = Workday 3`

Example 1: `Range(A1)=Format(MyNumber, "a #") = a 3`

Example 2: `Range(A1)=Format(MyNumber, "# Workday") = 4 Workday`

Issue: `Range(A1)=Format(MyNumber, "Workday #") = 3ork2a2`

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: @VigneshKumarA i've been to that webpage, but i cannot get it to work

Answer (score 2):

`w`, `d` and `y` are special characters within number formatting. You can escape them with the `\` to display them as a literal character.

```
Range("A1").Value = Format(myNumber, "\Work\da\y #")
```

More detail from the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) documentation:

> To display a character that has special meaning as a literal character, precede it with a backslash (`\`)... Examples of characters that can't be displayed as literal characters are the date-formatting and time-formatting characters (a, c, d, h, m, n, p, q, s, t, w, y, /, and :)...

Note, `Format` returns a `String` - so you could just do the following:

```
Range("A1").Value = "Workday " & myNumber
```